# How to get this question reopened?

Tags: support

[What resolution images could I use for posters on the wall?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73163/69210) is marked as a duplicate but I got a badge for Notable Question because it is much more natural to search for the phrase in the title also the answer is much more practical than the duplicate.

So how about we reverse which one is closed?

Comment: 3k/81 =~ 37 hits per month for yor post, the other is 25k/63 =~ 397 hits per month, which indicates that most likely the asnwer is more searched. OR that the search engine can understand those to be the same question. this disproves the claim that your question is somehow more beneficial as a natural finding target. But i dont generally disagree with the premise of your question. Its one of those it happens things, i think closing is a bit problematic in general. Anwyay why dont you rewrite my answer into the other thread.

Comment: me doing free labor for this mess when they _close my questions_?

Comment: I bet the benefit is bigger than anything you get from opening your question. Protip: Assume no one cares is the trick to being succesful on SE

Comment: That "free labor" comment just cracks me up `:)`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I'm seeing a good reason to close the [original question that is linked as a duplicate](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-at-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolution-shoul):

- 37 upvotes (vs. 1)
- 25k views (vs. 3k)
- Framed in a more general way (vs. strictly discussing posters on a wall).

The reason we keep duplicates is exactly because it makes an issue easier to search, but there is not really an advantage to scatter answers all over the place. Reopening the question would risk attracting more answers about resolution when they already exist.

Comment: i just wish i could delete my question why do i even bother

Comment: @chx why is it a problem that your question got closed? What loss it is for you personally if somebody says that hey hey yeah by the way the main discussion is here? You got your answer, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

The system is working as intended, your question is driving traffic to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.. but a question that takes **6 years** to acquire the "Notable question" badge is **not** a well trafficked question.

Those 3K views (and the badge) just means some combination of words hit your question rather than the more technical, and appropriate, duplicate.

It's not a bad thing to funnel searchers to a more in-depth answer.

If **any** question at **any** stack is there long enough.. it will trigger the "notable question" badge. The badge doesn't *really* mean anything. It certainly doesn't mean the question is more valuable.

I'd point out that the (open) duplicate **also** garnered the "Notable Question" badge. In fact, 5 times as much as your question.

The original question posted by @DA01 was *specifically* created because we were getting *a lot* of "what resolution" questions at the time. And rather than having essentially the *same* answers across myriad questions, the answers were intentionally more in depth and technical for *that* question so it would serve as a "holding space" for answers to any of the various "what resolution/ppi" questions. In other words... the "duplicate" was posted *intentionally* to drive less technically phrased questions regarding the same issue to it.

Answer (score 0):

Being closed as a duplicate isn't intended to be any kind of *punishment*, it's specifically designed to lead to the same set of answers by different search routes.
It *improves* the stack by being easier to find. Keeping them completely separate would dilute the available information.

Comment: Being closed as a duplicate isn't intended to be any kind of punishment, <= that's news to me and suspect quite a few powerdrunk people and sometimes mods too on various SE sites. (Yes, I do have a specific one in mind.)

Comment: @chx - from the man himself, over a decade ago - [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)